# Show that $n = 3^{100} + 2$ is not a prime number.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-reciprocity

So I have to prove that $n = 3^{100} + 2$ is not a prime number while we assume that $X^2 - 53$ has no zeroes in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Because we are working with quadratic reciprocity in this chapter, I assumed that $\big(\frac{53}{n}\big) = -1$ and by the law of quadratic reciprocity, we know that $\big(\frac{n}{53}\big) = -1$. However, I have no clue how I could use this to prove that $n$ is not prime.

Comment: $3^{100}+2$ has [8 divisors](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+3%5E(100)%2B2)

Comment: You've written at the beginning "So I have to prove that $n=3^{100}+2$ is a prime number". Nevertheless, in the end, you claim that you want "to prove that $n$ is not prime"...

Comment: $3^{100}+2 \equiv 12^2 \mod 53$ so $\left( \frac{n}{53}\right) = 1$.

Comment: Nice, @Robert Israel, but how do we know it is $12^2$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I don't understand how it follows that $n$ is no prime number when $\big(\frac{n}{53}\big) =1$

Comment: @Mee98 You used quadratic reciprocity to deduce it was $-1$ if $n$ was prime.

Comment: @FareedAF $53$ is not very big.  You can enumerate $1^2 \mod 53$, $2^2 \mod 53$, ..., $26^2 \mod 53$.

Comment: Have you learned how to compute $(n/53) = 1$ by quadratic reciprocity? That's your sought contradiction. If  you haven't then it's not hard to show directly that $n$ is a square mod $53$ (I can show you how if need be, but using reciprocity is easiest and likely what is intended).

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/31278/242) for a general  square test $\!\bmod n\ \ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a proof that the true $(3^{100}+2|53)=+1$, here is my approach:

Multiply be $3^4$, a known square, so:

$(3^{100}+2|53)=(3^{104}+3|53)$

where $2×3^4=162\equiv 3\bmod 53$.  The exponent on $3$ in the large term is now a multiple of $52$ forcing $3^{104}\equiv 1$ By Fermat's Little Theorem.  Thereby

$(3^{100}+2|53)=(1+3|53)=(2^2|53)=+1$

but you found that a prime number for $(3^{100}+2)$ should have given the Legendre symbol $-1$.  As an old hit song says, this is how it is when doves cry.

---

Even though the above Legendre symbol is $+1$, what causes $X^2-53=0$ to have no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a prime factor $p$ of $n=3^{100}+2$ for which $(53|p)=-1$.  The above proof does not identify any such factors, but the factor $37121$ quoted by others has this property.

Comment: Right. Had the OP replied to my comment I was going to note $\large \!\bmod 53\!:\,3^{\large 4} n\equiv 2^{\large 2}\,$ so $\,\large\,n\equiv (2/9)^{\large 2},\,$ essentially the same as above (but doesn't require any knowledge of Legendre symbols).